# why does my code not destroy all the objects of a list, and instead it randomly saves some of them? (unity 2d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first of all thank you for your time and im sorry for both my english and my low skills. Basically im doing this endless runner, where the player moves forward and jump over stuff. To make it endless i made a script that randomly chooses a prefabbetween those i attached to the script, and spawns it at the end of the position (using an empty object) of the other platform spawned before. To reset the game after you lose, i need to remove all the platforms spawned and saved in the list, but my problem is that every once in a while the script will skip one of them causing it to remain after the reset and restart.
here is my code:

```
 public void Reset()
    {
        deathMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < generatore.getPooled().Count; i++)
        {
            if (generatore.getPooled()[i] == null)
            {
                i++;
            }

            else
            {
                generatore.getPooled()[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                if (!generatore.getPooled()[i].gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    Destroy(generatore.getPooled()[i].gameObject);
                }
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    if (generatore.getPooled()[i - 1] == null && generatore.getPooled()[i + 1] == null)
                    {
                        Destroy(generatore.getPooled()[i].gameObject);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        player.transform.position = playerStartPoint;
        generatore.SetEndPosition(endPosition);
        player.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        scoreManager.scoreCounter = 0;
        scoreManager.scoreIncrease = true;
    }
```

it basically gets the platforms of the list (generatore.getPooled()), sets them inactive and then removes them one by one. I had to set them inactive before removing them because for some reasons,  it skips even more platforms if i only remove them , and i even tried to remove the ones that the script skips by adding:

```
if (generatore.getPooled()[i - 1] == null && generatore.getPooled()[i + 1] == null)
                    {
                        Destroy(generatore.getPooled()[i].gameObject);
                    }
```

but it still skips them.
[Here is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juXUJ.jpg)

Comment: Because you start at the bottom and work up so if you had numbered objects 1234, and you get to 2 and destroy it. Theres a chance 3 will now move to where 2 was so the next item is 4. Always start at the end and work back down

Comment: I'd probably get rid of that extra `i++` you have.  Change your if-block to just `if (generatore.getPooled()[i] != null)`

Comment: @BugFinder so you are saying i should set i to generatore.getPooled().count and go back to 0?

Comment: @LarsTech yes, you are right

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what `generatore.getPooled()` returns exactly but in general: Why repeatedly calling this instead of storing it in the first place? What exactly does this return?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all why are you doing `i++` inn the first `if` case inside the loop?

   Since `i++` is done anyway after every iteration this **skips** not the current but the **next** item as well! You would rather want to use [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) instead.
2. Then you are repeatedly calling

   ```
   generator.getPooled()
   ```

   which always returns a new list (I guess). This is not only bad performance wise but also while you remove entries from the pool (I suppose that somewhere happens while you destroy them) all other items most probably move one step up and thereby change their indices. So since you continuously increase the index `i` it might happen that an element was moved to an index you already passed so this again leads to skipping some of them.
3. And then your conditions for calling `Destroy` are quite redundant. Right after

   ```
   someGameObject.SetActive(false);
   ```

   the check for

   ```
   if(!someGameObject.activeInHierarchy)
   ```

   will always be true *(except there is some dark magic going on in a script where in `OnDisable` you set yourself to active again - which sounds pretty uncanny to do ^^)*.
4. And since you destroy it anyway (see 3.) there actually is no need at all for setting it to inactive first.
5. And also since you will always destroy the object (see 3.) the next check via indices makes no sense since you already destroyed the object anyway.

So in summary your code would shrink down to

```
foreach (var pooled in generatore.getPooled())
{
    if (!pooled) continue;
  
    Destroy(pooled.gameObject);
}
// TODO: clear the pool so there are no null elements remaining forever
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works perfectly now, im new to unity and c# and im trying to learn the best i can. Still a long road i guess ahah

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a specific tag to your platforms

then try using a foreach loop for destroying them, like this:

```
      foreach (GameObject platform4delete in 
               GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("somePlatfromTag"))
        {
            Destroy(platform4delete);
        }
```

it probably will delete all platforms without missing any